# image and script link not good because of subfolder

Tags: php, mysql, processwire

I am new to ProcessWire and I have a simple question.
I transferred from being hosted on a server to running form a local site and some images, scripts, and links to pages are not showing up correctly.

The Homepage can be found at `"http://localhost/restaurant/release/"` and, for example, a relative link to some script is currently something like `<script src="/site/templates/scripts/f.js">`.

The problem is that, when the browser tries to access this link, it actually gets `"http://localhost/site/templates/scripts/f.js"` 
instead of `"http://localhost/restaurant/release/site/templates/scripts/f.js"`.

How does ProcessWire handle these kinds of links? And how do I fix them?

Comment: How do you link to the script in your PHP template file? Please add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `base` tag in your HTML `head`:

```
<base href="http://localhost/restaurant/release">
```

Use your links as per normal:

```
<script src="/site/templates/scripts/f.js">
```

Alternatively, simply omit the leading slash from the script `src`.